# A pond contains two types of fish: 10 blue and 9 red. Among red fish, $\frac{1}{4}$ are poisonous and among blue fish $\frac{3}{5}$ are poisonous....

Tags: probability, solution-verification, conditional-probability, problem-solving

> A pond contains two types of fish: 10 blue and 9 red. Among red fish, $\frac{1}{4}$ are poisonous and among blue fish $\frac{3}{5}$ are poisonous. A woman and a man catch a fish. They cook and eat half the fish each. If you eat the poisonous fish, the odds of getting sick are $\frac{75}{100}$ for a man and $\frac{45}{100}$ for a woman. Calculate:

> a) the probability that the woman will become ill(Pw)

> b) the probability that at most one of the two gets sick

> c) the probability that no one will get sick

> d) the probability that they ate a poisonous blue fish if the man became ill

> e) the probability that they ate a poisonous fish if no one got sick.

a)

Probability of catching a blue poisonous fish is Pb=$\frac{3}{5}\cdot 10$ the probability of catching a red poisonous fish is Pv$\frac{1}{4}\cdot 9$ and the probability of the woman getting sick is $\frac{45}{100}$ so we have Pw = $\frac{3}{5}\cdot 10 \cdot \frac{45}{100}$ + $\frac{1}{ 4}\cdot 10 \cdot \frac{45}{100}$

b)

Probability of a woman getting sick plus the probability of a man getting sick.

Pt = Pw + Pm = $\frac{3}{5}\cdot 10 \cdot \frac{45}{100}$ + $\frac{1}{ 4}\cdot 10 \cdot \frac{45}{100} + \frac{3}{5}\cdot 10 \cdot \frac{45}{100}$ + $\frac{1}{ 4}\cdot 10 \cdot \frac{75}{100}$

c) 1 - Pt

d)$\frac{\frac{75}{100} \cdot \frac{3}{4}\cdot10}{\frac{75}{100}}$

e)
The probability that none got sick is $Pn=\frac{25}{100} \cdot \frac{55}{100}$.

The probability that they ate some poisonous fish is $Pp= \frac{1}{4} \cdot 9 + \frac{3}{5} \cdot 10$. So $P = \frac{Pn \cdot Pp}{Pn}$

Are these alternatives correct?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: First thing to note, how can a fish be a quarter poisonous? Secondly, who catches the fish first? Or do you assume they have no influence over each other?

Comment: You have to calculate the *probability* that a blue fish is caught, which is $\frac{10}{10 + 9} = \frac{10}{19}$.

Comment: Your probability in (a) is over $1$ ($=3.825$), what does that mean?

Comment: Note that the probability of catching a blue fish is not affected if the fish was poisonous or not. They are independent.

Comment: @soupless,  Clearly they are dependent because when you catch a poisonous fish it is more likely to be blue than red.  On average $6$ of the $10$ blue fish are poisonous, while only $2.25$ of the $9$ red fish are expected to be so.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I think you misunderstood my statement. What I mean is that the probability of catching a blue fish is not affected by the probability of it being poisonous. Just because it is poisonous does not mean that it will be harder to catch.

Comment: @soupless.  No, I understood the statement, it is just not true.  Each individual fish may be equally hard to catch, but the numbers in each category mater.

Comment: @GrahamKemp What I'm referring to is your statement "Each individual fish may be equally hard to catch" as I am only referring to the probability of catching a blue fish, regardless if it's poisonous or not. I stated it because OP stated that the probability of catching a blue poisonous fish is $\frac35\cdot 10$ which is wrong and should be a solution using Bayes' theorem.

Comment: It's using the wrong values, but is the correct approach.$$\mathsf P(b\cap p)~{=\mathsf P(p\mid b)~\mathsf P(b)\\=\tfrac 35\cdot\tfrac{10}{19}}$$

Comment: Now calculating the conditional probability of a catch being blue when given that it is poisonous will need to use Bayes' Rule *because* the events are *not* independent.